# Access scheduledLocalNotifications for iOS in react-native

Tags: ios, react-native

I want to access the scheduled local notifications for iOS in `react-native`. I see that there is a variable `scheduledLocalNotifications` in the native SDK that can be used to access the scheduled local notifications but it is not exposed in `react-native` and I am not sure how to return an array from native code to `react-native`. The `react-native` document suggests to store the data the `RCTRootView` but since `PushNotificationIOS` is an API and not a component, there is not `RCTRootView` attached to it.

If anyone knows how to access `scheduledLocalNotifications` variable in `react-native`, please let me know.

Comment: There's a pull request that adds what you need: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/6907

Comment: @DanielBasedow thanks for pointing me to the PR, I searched for scheduledLocalNotifications on the repo and nothing showed up but this is exactly what I am looking for.